# Entity manager lifecycle in Weblogic

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, jta, weblogic12c

I have EAR application written with EJB 3.1, where I'm using JPA 2.0.
Persistance unit is configured to use JTA

```
<persistence-unit name="JPACommonParameters" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

I've created simple deployment, where in EJB I inject Entity manager just like this

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "JPACommonParameters")
protected EntityManager em;
```

Using this jpa I called simple query using createNamedQuery.
Application is deployed on WLS 12.1.1.0, managed server. 
After first deployment it is working. Everything is fine. 
After updating the same application without any change I've receiving ClastCastException as object returned from query is not the same as in application.

```
result = (ParamDef) em.createNamedQuery("ParamDef.findActiveParamDef").
getSingleResult();
```

After long investigation I've found, that problem is with classloader. Object returned from entity manager is loaded by different classloader(Classloader used during first deployment) than object ParamDef in bracket I'm casting.

Everything is working fine when I will restart manged wls server. 
My question is: How to configure application of wls to initialize entityManger every redeploy of application on server to get it working without restart.

Here is my pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>ofs-direct-services</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.oproc.first.app</groupId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>IT-app</artifactId>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>IT-app Integ. Tests for app</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <cxf.version>2.2.3</cxf.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-wls-remote-12.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oproc.first.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>customer-app-services</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oproc.first.common.parameters</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-parameters-services</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oproc.first.common.parameters</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-parameters-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oproc.first.common.parameters</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-parameters-db</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oproc.first.common.parameters</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-parameters-services</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oproc.first</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-tuxedo-connector-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>  
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oproc.first</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-tuxedo-connector-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>  
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oproc.first</groupId>
        <artifactId>db4b-db</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>no_integration_testing</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-test</id>
                            <configuration>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>integration_testing</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <compilerArguments>
                            <endorseddirs>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorseddirs>
                        </compilerArguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>surefire-it</id>
                            <phase>integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Please post your POM.xml file. The trick is on the building step.

Comment: @Sam, I've added pom.xml to the question post.